# Filling results of linear regression into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running a regression between two stocks:

(y=bank_matrix['EXO.MI']

and

x=bank_matrix['LDO.MI']).

My task is to update the slope coefficient every 20 days (lookback). In short, I want to have a list of slope coefficients starting from day 20 (my lookback). So I run this regression model called reg.

In the meantime, I create:

A)3 empty lists: Intercetta=[], Hedge=[], Residuals=[]

B)1 Dataframe called Regressione where I want to copy the results of my regression (Intercept,Slope and residuals) inside this dataframe columns (['Intercept','Hedge','Residuals']).

Now the whole code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader as pdr
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()


tickers=['EXO.MI','LDO.MI']
end=datetime.date.today()
gap=datetime.timedelta(days=650)
start=end- gap

Bank=pdr.get_data_yahoo(tickers,start=start,end=end)
bank_matrix=Bank['Adj Close']
bank_matrix=bank_matrix.dropna()

exor=bank_matrix['EXO.MI']
leonardo=bank_matrix['LDO.MI']

Regressione=pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros((len(exor),3)),columns=['Intercetta','Hedge','Residuals'],index=bank_matrix['EXO.MI'].index)
lookback=20
Hedge=[]
Intercetta=[]
Residuals=[]

for i in range(lookback,len(exor)):
    reg=LinearRegression().fit(bank_matrix[['LDO.MI']][i-lookback+1:i],bank_matrix[['EXO.MI']][i-lookback+1:i])
    # Regressione.iloc[Regressione[i,'Hedge']]=reg.coef_[0]
    Hedge.append(reg.coef_[0])
    Intercetta.append(reg.intercept_)
    y_pred=reg.predict(bank_matrix[['LDO.MI']][lookback:])
    Residuals.append(bank_matrix[['EXO.MI']][lookback:].to_numpy()-y_pred)
Regressione=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Intercetta,Hedge,Residuals)),columns=['Intercetta','Hedge','Residuals'])
Regressione.set_index(bank_matrix[['EXO.MI']].index[lookback:],inplace=True)
```

NOW THE FINAL QUESTION: Why in my final dataframe 'Regressione', the third column('Residuals') is an horizontal array???

Comment: Because you insert it that way. Better question is - what is that you wanted to have there? I.e. what is your desired output?

Comment: My output is what I already said: a dataframe(Regressione) with 3 columns (Intercetta,Hedge,Residuals).Every row must contains 3 elements, 1 for column. But I really don't understand why, when appending 'y_pred' to 'Residuals', it becomes an horizontal series. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Ok, not executing your code, what you're appending to each row of Residuals is: ```bank_matrix[['EXO.MI']][lookback:].to_numpy()-y_pred``` it does look exactly like a horizontal list...

Comment: Ok but HOW to have a my 3th column (Residuals) looking the same as the other two (Intercetta, Residuals)???? I need the column vector of residuals to build my signals so I have to work with and plot them .

Comment: Ok, looking into that, what's ```exor``` - I'm getting ```exor is not defined``` error during execution

Comment: Sorry, my fault:                                                               exor=bank_matrix['EXO.MI']                                                  leonardo=bank_matrix['LDO.MI']

Answer (score 1):

so, firstly I think these 2 lines you are doing completely wrong:

```py
y_pred=reg.predict(bank_matrix[['LDO.MI']][lookback:])
Residuals.append(bank_matrix[['EXO.MI']][lookback:].to_numpy()-y_pred)
```

You basically try to run linear regression for all the points starting 1 to 20, then 2 to 21, 3 to 22 etc. Then you try to fit that regression to data from observation 20 onward. So you get the model for e.g. 5 to 24 and based on it you predict observations 20 till the end, and take the difference between that prediction and actuals (mind that `bank_matrix[['EXO.MI']][lookback:].to_numpy()` doesn't change during your `for` loop).

I suppose what would make more sense here would be:

```py
y_pred=reg.predict(bank_matrix[['LDO.MI']][i-lookback+1:i])
Residuals.append(bank_matrix[['EXO.MI']][i-lookback+1:i].to_numpy()-y_pred)
```

So you would take error of the model, or:

```py
y_pred=reg.predict(bank_matrix[['LDO.MI']][i:])
Residuals.append(bank_matrix[['EXO.MI']][i:].to_numpy()-y_pred)
```

So you would try to fit prediction based on the current time span to the data going forward.

Now first option will produce lists of 19 elements per row, while the other one will produce list of 430, decreasing by 1 per row, until 1 in the last row. Because these are residuals - so you have a line, with a slope, and hedge 1 per given time span, but then you have number of observation within this range producing each different result. So depending on how do you want to express it - you can make it sum of square residuals, or maybe take mean residual - you can make it one number only by applying some further transformation to it.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hi Gregorz thanks for your help and sorry for my delay. You are right, I was confusing the timeframes for regression periods, but even worse, I wasn't understanding that, even if there is 1 only hedge and Intercetta computed for every 20 days, residuals remains 20! So,I think that I'm supposed to do a mean for every row of my Residuals. I wrote:  res=[i.mean() for i in Residuals].  At that point I just wrote: plt.hist(res) and plt.plot(res) to have the confirm of quasi-normal distribution of my residuals.

Comment: By the way: in my for-loop Regression, I replaced 'Residuals.append....'  with 'Residuals.append(reg.residues_). Is that 'reg.residues_' the same as the mean of residuals for every 20 days sub-periods???

Answer (score 0):

From the doc:

> If a list of dict/series is passed and the keys are all contained in the DataFrame’s index, the order of the columns in the resulting DataFrame will be unchanged.
>
> Iteratively appending rows to a DataFrame can be more computationally intensive than a single concatenate. A better solution is to append those rows to a list and then concatenate the list with the original DataFrame all at once.

You need to use `df.loc` for example to modify the data in your dataframe...